# Getting different results for max(max(x, key=len )) and max( max(i) for i in x)

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning

I am trying to classify reviews on imdb dataset using deep learning. Here I have a list of variable size lists. I am interested in finding the list with maximum size among these variable size lists. But I am getting different results from 2 different methods. can anyone tell which is correct.

my code is as following:-

```
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential

#importing datasets
(x,y),(xtest,ytest) = imdb.load_data(num_words = 10000)

#trying for loop method
max(max(i) for i in x)

#trying max method
max(max(x, key = len))
```

The for-loop method is generating 9999 whereas max method is generating 9890.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `max(i)` gets maximum by value and other by length. Consider: '009' and '90'. `max(i)` returns 90, while other returns 009.

Comment: @Austin Thanks for the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that x is a list of lists, `max(x, key = len)` gives you the longest list in `x`, so when you do `max(max(x, key = len))`, you get the maximum element inside the longest list, which is not what you want. Remove the outer `max` and it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.